# Basic page still showing in view that filters out basic page content from view

Tags: 7, nodes, views

I made a view that is only supposed to show Album, Mixtape, and Artist content types, but the basic page I made called "About Us" is showing up.  I've tried deleting that content and re-making it and then doing the same with the view but it *still* shows up!

I'm attaching a couple of pictures to show you what I mean.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found out why this was happening, but I found a workaround for it.
Add another filter that says content cannot be of type: Basic Page.
It's not pretty and I would prefer to not have to use that and fix the problem instead, but if you're pressed for time this will work.